# How to add any new library like spark-sftp into my Pyspark code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When Im trying to set a package dependency "spark-sftp" in my Spark conf, I get ClassNotFoundException. But it works when i execute the script using:

spark-submit --packages com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.1 test.py

Below is my code. Can someone tell me how can i execute my pyspark script 
 by without passing the package as an argument to spark-submit?

```
import sys
import datetime
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext, Row, HiveContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

#Create new config
conf = (pyspark.conf.SparkConf()
.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "16g")
.set("spark.driver.memory", "20g")
.set("spark.executor.memory", "20g")
.set("spark.executor.cores", "5")
.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors", "24")
.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors", "6")
.set("spark.submit.deployMode", "client")
.set("spark.jars.packages", "com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.1")
.set("spark.python.worker.memory", "4g")
.set("spark.default.parallelism", "960")
.set("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "4g")
.setMaster("yarn-client"))


# Create new context
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AppName").config(conf=conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")


df = spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.sftp").option("host", "HOST").option("username", "HOSTNAME").option("password", "pass").option("fileType", "csv").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/test/sample.csv")
```

Output:
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.springml.spark.sftp. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springml.spark.sftp.DefaultSource

Answer (score -1):

While submitting spark job, you can specify what packages to install. For this one you can specify this maven dependency as:

```
> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to run the pyspark app by passing --packages argument during spark-submit but what im trying to know is 
 whether can i set the packages inside the pyspark code file like below during configuration and run the app without java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.



.set("spark.jars.packages", "com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.1")

Comment: @Manideep do you able to run  pyspark code using jars?