# Use spark-sftp jar in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, sftp

Already run below pasted code successfully using

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark --packages com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.3`

but I want to run code using jars for that download jars(https://spark-packages.org/package/springml/spark-sftp) and copied in $SPARK_HOME/jars folder
My code snippet as below

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc_conf = SparkConf()
sc_conf.setAppName("app_name")
sc_conf.setMaster('local[*]')
context = SparkContext(conf=sc_conf)
spark = SparkSession(context)

FTP_HOST ="host name"
FTP_USER ="user name"
FTP_PASS= "server name"
FTP_PEM_FILE_PATH="private pem file path"

sftp_df = spark\
    .read\
    .format("com.springml.spark.sftp")\
    .option("host",FTP_HOST)\
    .option("username", FTP_USER)\
    .option("pemPassphrase", FTP_PASS)\
    .option("pem", FTP_PEM_FILE_PATH)\
    .option("fileType", "csv")\
    .option("delimiter", ",")\
    .option("multiLine", "true")\
    .option("inferSchema", "true")\
    .option("header", "false")\
    .load("/csv file path")
sftp_df.count()
```

Error stack:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o62.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.springml.spark.sftp. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springml.spark.sftp.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$20.apply(DataSource.scala:634)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:634)
    ... 13 more
```

Found the same question but not resolved just tried with updated spark(2.4.3)
[How to add any new library like spark-sftp into my Pyspark code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52067494/7130689)